# Get Rid of space between elements while using split()

Tags: python-3.x

How to get rid of the space between elements while using split("")

I am converting string of tuples in to tuple of strings

```
line = '(black,black,blue,cyan)'
line = line[1:-1]
line_split = line.split(",")
print(line_split)
line_tuple = tuple(line_split)
print(line_tuple)
```

Expected output - ('black','black','blue','cyan') with No spaces

Output Received - ('black', 'black', 'blue', 'cyan') with spaces between , and next element

Comment: You do not have spaces between elements after using `split()`. The spaces only appear in the representation of the tuple when it is printed. So the elements of the `line_tuple` tuple are strings without any space, but when you print the tuple, it is represented as a string of CSV with spaces between elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is only the string representation of a tuple, your elements don't contain any spaces. But if you insist removing the spaces:

```py
output = '(' + ','.join(line_tuple) + ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
line = '(black,black,blue,cyan)'

# stripping "'(" and "')" and then adding inner items into a list
lst_of_strings = line.strip('\'()').split(',')

# building the comma separated string
inside = ','.join(repr(item) for item in lst_of_strings)

# final result
print('(' + inside + ')')
```

output :

```
('black','black','blue','cyan')
```

Note : `repr()` function adds quotation marks around the string.

Also I should mention that, this is just a representation ! It's a string now, not a tuple anymore.